# How do you run express and socket.io on the same port

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, socket.io

its always annoying i have to always run listen to a new port in my app.js meaning eg i can access my website with localhost:3000 and localhost:4000 and socket.io on my site works only using localhost:4000. I just pushed it to heroku and realised i cant even change the port on heroku

this is what i have

**app.js:**

```
var express = require("express");
var io = require('socket.io')
var port = 3000;

var app = express()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = io.listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

module.exports = io;
```

**client.js:**

```
var socket = io('http://localhost/');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm able to do what you want with:

```
var exp = express();
var server = require('http').Server(exp)
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

//setup stuff

server.listen(3000)
```

Comment: Haha ! we meet again :D this however gives me  listen `EADDRINUSE`

Comment: EADDRINUSE means something else is listening on that port.  Could be in the node app, could be some other process.  make sure you `killall node` in your bash shell to kill all other node processes.  Also make sure no other code is doing `listen`.  I see ` , io = io.listen(server);` in your code.  Did you remove that and all other "listens"?

Comment: yes no other process is running except from when i do npm start. How come i can already connect to `localhost:3000` without specifying the server stuff in my express app. I dont have to do `server.listen(3000)`

Comment: im saying there should only be one `listen` and that is `server.listen(3000)`, remove the line `  , io = io.listen(server);` from your code

Comment: last time you had code you weren't sharing.  your going to have to figure out what else is listening on that port.  because that is what that error means

Comment: sorry about that @mattyice, just figured it out ! for some reason another process was using 3000 which i cant still figure out. so i decided to hard code the port in app.js `app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);`

Comment: If you used the express generator it has the server.listen(port) in bin/www. This was causing the EADDRINUSE for me.

Comment: you have another process running or other code that is listening on that port.  try `$ killall node` in Terminal before you run or try to run only the code above

Comment: Hi. I think I am having the same problem. I tried to do as your answer, but I have "Port 3000 is already in use". I then try to do    

     $killall node  , but I have 'killall is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Are you on mac or windows?

Comment: I am on window. I think I have the problem like @duckworth. I used express generator, and I see "var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');" in bin/www. Would you mind to let me know what should I do to make io socket is in the same port 3000?

Comment: Ok yeah killall won't work on windows.  Open up task manager and kill all the node processes you have running.

Comment: I still have "Port 3000 is already in use". I am trying to comment out `var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);` in bin/www, but it causes app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest version of express 4 + socket.io 1.0 (which I use myself) is this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("server started on port 3000");
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

I don't honestly know why your version doesn't work, but have advised several people to follow this sequence (which I got from the documentation) and it has worked for myself and for them.  It probably has to do with `io` getting plugged into express 4 appropriately and not using the general `http` module, but `express` instead.

Comment: Didnt work for me, i get the warning that the port is in use.

Comment: @SvenB - that means you already have something on that server listening to that port.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Downvoters who leave no explanation don't help people improve their answers.